# What does the word "take" mean in the sentence below? does it mean replace?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The context:

> #### The uses for UWB in automotive and industrial settings are even more immense.
>
> Since UWB can sense location in 1/1000th the time, it **takes** traditional technologies so that decision-making will get faster and more precise. The technology will enable new ways for cars and industrial robots not only to sense their environments, but take actions, or actuate based on that data.

for more context, please check at https://readwrite.com/2019/12/13/follow-the-puck/

What does the word "take" mean in the sentence below? does it mean replace?

Answer (score 4):

This sentence has been edited incorrectly. There are two options for what it is probably intended to say:

> UWB can sense location in 1/1000th the time it takes traditional technologies, so that decision-making will get faster and more precise. The technology will enable new ways for cars and industrial robots not only to sense their environments, but take actions, or actuate based on that data.
>
> Since UWB can sense location in 1/1000th the time it takes traditional technologies, decision-making will get faster and more precise. The technology will enable new ways for cars and industrial robots not only to sense their environments, but take actions, or actuate based on that data.

In both options, it should now be clear that **take** refers to time. See **take (NEED)** in this [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take) definition.

Comment: In the first option, "so that" can be reduced to "so"?

Comment: @wuhan: yes, it can.

Answer (score 0):

**Takes** appears to be used here in the sense of **requires** or **needs**.

For example, we say; **It takes four people to lift the piano**, meaning that four people are required to do this.

However, I find the sentence quoted strange and not clear.

(JavaLatte's better answer below resolves this confusion)